# SQL Server Stored procedure error inserting long strings: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion, sqldatatypes

I am attempting to insert a long string in JSON format,  ie `#jsonLayoutProperties#`, into an MS SQL Server table using a stored procedure. The string could be long e.g. 10,000 characters+. Which `cfsqltype` should I use in my stored procedure? `cf_sql_longvarchar` seems to be the only option, there does not appear to be a `cfsqltype` that maps to `nvarchar(max)`.

The error I get is below. It appears that the string is being truncated. Any help would be very welcome.

**Error:**

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Unclosed quotation mark
>   after the character string.

**CFStoredproc:**

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="docs" procedure="UpdateLayout">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" type="in" value="#Session.Userdata['ID']#">                 <!--- @AccountID --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" type="in" value="#ObjectID#">                               <!--- @ObjectID --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" type="in" value="#jsonLayoutProperties#">               <!--- @Properties --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" type="in" value="0">                                        <!--- @Revision --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" type="in" value="#Session.Userdata['ID']#">                 <!--- @UpdatedID --->
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" type="inout" value="0" variable="LayoutID">                 <!--- @ID --->
</cfstoredproc>
```

Comment: (Edit) If you run execute the procedure (with the same values) in SSMS, does it execute successfully? *RE: there does not appear to be a cfsqltype that maps to nvarchar(max)* There is, and it is almost what you guessed: `cf_sql_longnvarchar` (note the middle "n" for **n**varchar)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a type issue.

```
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string.
```

To me means you could have unescaped quotes in your string.  Can you check this?

Comment: The variable is valid json (isJSON = YES) so I think the string itself is fine. The error is caused (i think) as only the first n characters are being passed to the database by cf_sql_longvarchar.

Comment: @Paul have you tried using CF_SQL_NVARCHAR instead?  After rereading, I saw that you used nvarchar and not varchar

Comment: I have tried cf_sql_nvarchar, cf_sql_longvarchar, cf_sql_text and actually "cf_sql_max" just to see what happened, all with the same, original result.

Comment: Have you at succeeded with shorter strings?  I would try short ones and work my way up with a data type that works and try to identify at what length it breaks

Comment: Given that procparams are supposed to escape apostrophes, why would you think it's an unescaped character?

Comment: longnvarchaar failed also... after checking all sorts of combinations of string and also different lengths of string, I found the issue. My stored procedure is dynamic i.e. exec(@sql), my @sql was set to nvarchar(4000) and it was that which was causing the problem. So annoyed that I missed this. Thanks very much for your help everyone.

Comment: *RE:  exec(@sql)* Ouch... that makes it vulnerable to sql injection. Look into `sp_executesql` or something similar.